# Kaminari custom config per page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

I have on my Kaminari config:

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.default_per_page = 50
end
```

and I want to set a custom value for per page for this action:

```
@my_models = MyModel.all.per(20)
```

I would like to set like this:

```
@my_models = MyModel.all.per(Kaminari.my_custom_per_page)
```

because I would like to change this to test my action with less objects.
Is it possible?

Comment: Just do `MyModel.page(1).per(20)`

Comment: I need something to change the value on my test files...

Comment: What if you set the `Kaminari.configure` differently in your `test.rb` environment file?

Answer (score 0):

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

paginates_per 20

...

end